# How to read a URL that contains "https://uswest.xyz.com/@admin?deep_link_id=35&deep_link_type=user" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

How can I read the below [URL](https://uswest.xyz.com/@admin?deep_link_id=35&deep_link_type=user&%243p=e_md&%24original_url=https%3A%2F%2Fuswest.edcastqa.com%2F%40admin%3Fdeep_link_id%3D35%26deep_link_type%3Duser&%24desktop_url=https%3A%2F%2Fuswest.edcastqa.com%2F%40admin%3Fdeep_link_id%3D35%26deep_link_type%3Duser&_branch_match_id=670200240024628044%22) in JS ?

I need to add a condition on `deep_link_type=user`

whenever `deep_link_type` is `user` I need to do something.

I know using split and includes methods. But is there any other way of doing this ?

How can I acheive this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use decodeURIComponent as follows

```js
const url = "https://uswest.xyz.com/@admin?deep_link_id=35&deep_link_type=user&%243p=e_md&%24original_url=https%3A%2F%2Fuswest.edcastqa.com%2F%40admin%3Fdeep_link_id%3D35%26deep_link_type%3Duser&%24desktop_url=https%3A%2F%2Fuswest.edcastqa.com%2F%40admin%3Fdeep_link_id%3D35%26deep_link_type%3Duser&_branch_match_id=670200240024628044"

const decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url)
if (decodedUrl.indexOf('deep_link_type=user') > -1) {
   console.log("deep link by user logic...")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const param = urlParams.get('deep_link_type');
if (param === 'user')
  ...
```